# Traditional vegetarian dishes in Bavaria?

Tags: germany, food-and-drink, munich

I'm off to Munich for a 3-day trip and I wonder what are some traditional vegetarian Bavarian dishes that I should not miss to taste? Is there any?

Comment: Why the comment-less downvotes? anti-vegs?

Comment: @sepher: I think because as it is written, the question is seen as both a list question and a opinion based one. Hence the close votes, too.

Comment: Here's a [good list](https://www.thelocal.de/20150930/top-10-traditional-german-vegetarian-dishes) and [SE Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) may offer some suggestions. And, keep in mind, they're vegetarian, but not vegan.

Comment: Oh, I can't see the close votes yet. I think it should be rephrased to "Is there any vegetarian Bavarian dishes served in Munich"?

Comment: Try delicious dishes from egg-legging milk pigs ;)

Comment: To answer the _are there traditional vegetarian dishes in Bavaria?_ - unless you count bread and beer, there certainly are no vegan ones. Vegetarian, I don't think so. They like their meat. Or pig's grease. Ans sausages. Lots of sausages. Even Sauerkraut has pig in it when done right.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks for the clarification, very helpful.

Comment: @DanubianSailor :)))))))))))))))))))) Now that I'm actually there, I understand your comments. Veg-friendly traditional Bavarian food? Oh, no way! Every single person that is sitting around me right now, is having all kinda sausages for breakfast!

Comment: I remember eating very nice Krautsalat (some sort of coleslaw) in Munich, but beware of any Speck (bacon)

Comment: Most of my knowledge about Germany is stereotypical in nature, but vegetarianism doesn't fit my stereotype.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm that's exactly the same reason people don't believe me when I say I've moved to Bulgaria to enjoy their huge vegetarian and healthy focused cooking. And I don't know much about strictly Bavarian food (even if one of my fav restaurant in Italy is a traditional Bavarian), but when it comes to Germany...they have a huge amount of vegetarian dishes like every other culture on earth, and rightly so: meat historically has been expensive, precious, or even an exclusive for the nobles. We think of vegetarian as something unusual, but it's still our everyday food, we just don't realize it.

Comment: (note: I'm not in anyway advertising vegetarian food or a vegetarian lifestyle, everyone its own tastes and I really cannot care less what other people eat, as long as they are happy with their choices)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one dish typically found in most traditional Bavarian restaurants that indeed is vegetarian. It is not a traditional Bavarian dish but a traditional Swabian one, though.

This dish is called *Käsespätzle,* in Bavarian dialect it might also be written *Kasspatzn.* It consists of the traditional Swabian *Spätzle* (a type of noodles) with lots of molten cheese and optionally fried onions (both crispy and non-crispy although the former seems more common to me).

---

Furthermore, if you are into cold dishes or visiting a beer garden *(Biergarten),* you may also be interested in *Obazden.* This is most loosely described as a variant of cheese; more adequately it is whatever the kitchen had left over and is fitting to put into a creamy cheesy mixture. It has a strong taste and would typically be eaten with bread or pretzels. If you are in a part of a beer garden that includes service (especially note that in Munich many beer gardens are bring your own food), they will usually have pretzel with *Obazdem* on their menu.

Note that the spelling of *Obazda* is not fully fixed as it is a dialectal word. Note also that since it is grammatically a nominalised adjective (deriving from a past participle), it features a not-so-common (for nouns) declension which is frequently done wrong by non-Bavarians (‘Prussians’): *ein Obazda, der Obazde, des Obazden, mit Obazdem, den Obazden* to randomly jump through a few different cases.

Comment: Thank you so much Jan, for taking the time and writing such comprehensive answer. I'll do my best to find a place that serves Käsespätzle in my last hours of stay here at Munich.

Comment: @sepehr, note that Käsespätzle also exists in non-vegetarian variants (they might add e.g. bacon), so better ask.

Comment: So what is the infinitve? Obazen? What does it mean?

Comment: @CarstenS Or *anbazen* or *anmanschen* in standard German.

Answer (score 3):

Another traditional vegetarian Bavarian dish would be bread dumplings with Mushroom sauce (in German it is called *Semmelknödel mit Champignonsauce*).
Or if you are craving something sweet: *Kaiserschmarrn* - it is sweet dough parts that are baked in a pan and served with applesauce or plum jam.

Comment: Half of Austria is now furiously typing a comment that Kaiserschmarrn is definitely not Bavarian ;)

Comment: Maybe I should have made clear that it was originally from Austria 0:) but you can get very good Kaiserschmarrn in Bavaria as well, so I think it is ok to suggest trying it in Bavaria ;)